# Windows Phone back button not being handled

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, prism, win-universal-app

I have registered a handler with the `HardwareButtons.BackPressed` event, performed some logic and then set the handled property in the args to true if it applies. The handler runs through without any issue, and the Handled property gets set. The phone still navigates back outside of the app. Am I misunderstanding how to use the event?

## Page

```
public sealed partial class FirstRunPage : VisualStateAwarePage
{
    public FirstRunPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed += (sender, args) =>
            {
                bool isHandled = false;
                Action handledCallback = () => isHandled = true;
                var state = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Callback", handledCallback } };
                ((INavigationAware)this.DataContext).OnNavigatedTo("Back", NavigationMode.Back, state);
                args.Handled = isHandled;
            };
#endif
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }
}
```

#### View model.

```
    public override void OnNavigatedTo(object navigationParameter, NavigationMode navigationMode, Dictionary<string, object> viewModelState)
    {
        if (navigationParameter == null || !navigationParameter.ToString().Equals("Back"))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!viewModelState.ContainsKey("Callback"))
        {
            return;
        }

        var callback = (Action)viewModelState["Callback"];

        // If the user is new, then we set it to false and invoke our callback.
        if (this.IsNewUser)
        {
            this.IsNewUser = false;
            callback();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

#### Update

I have modified my FirstRunPage to subscribe and unsubscribe as recommended by @Martin but it still closes the app.

```
public sealed partial class FirstRunPage : VisualStateAwarePage
{
    public FirstRunPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareBack_OnPressed;
#endif
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareBack_OnPressed;
#endif
    }

    private void HardwareBack_OnPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Action handledCallback = () => e.Handled = true;
        var state = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Callback", handledCallback } };

        ((INavigationAware)this.DataContext).OnNavigatedTo("Back", NavigationMode.Back, state);
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of @yasen I was able to get this resolved. The issue stems from the fact that the Prism library has your App.xaml.cs inherit from MvvmAppbase, which intercepts the `BackPressed` event.

To resolve this, I overrode the MvvmAppBase `OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed` and added a bit of logic to handle it.
My view model and view both implement a new interface called INavigateBackwards and they're used like this:

#### View Model

```
    public bool CanNavigateBack()
    {
        // If the new user is true, then we can't navigate backwards.
        // There isn't any navigation stack, so the app will die.
        bool canNavigate = !this.IsNewUser;

        // Disable the new user mode.
        this.IsNewUser = false;

        // Return so that the view can return to it's sign-in state.
        return canNavigate;
    }
```

#### View

```
public sealed partial class FirstRunPage : VisualStateAwarePage, INavigateBackwards
{
    private INavigateBackwards ViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return (INavigateBackwards)this.DataContext;
        }
    }

    public FirstRunPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public bool CanNavigateBack()
    {
        return ViewModel.CanNavigateBack();
    }
}
```

Then in the MvvmAppBase subclass, I determine if I need to handle the navigation or not.

#### MvvmAppBase child

```
    protected override void OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        var page = (Page)((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Content;
        if (page is INavigateBackwards)
        {
            var navigatingPage = (INavigateBackwards)page;
            if (!navigatingPage.CanNavigateBack())
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
        }

        base.OnHardwareButtonsBackPressed(sender, e);
    }
```

This allows my single view to have multiple states and the user to navigate back from one state to the previous without navigating to an entirely new view.

Comment: Always happy to help. :) You should mark this as answer by the way.

Comment: I will when I can, it told me that I had to wait 2 days

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your application closes is that the same handler is called more than just once. First handler sets the `Handled` property to `true`, but any other subsequent call for the same event fire sets it back to `false`.

To illustrate it, try this:

```
public sealed partial class FirstRunPage : VisualStateAwarePage
{
    public FirstRunPage()
    {
       // ...
       InitializeComponent();
       HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;   
       HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed; 
    }

    void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isHandled = false;
        Action handledCallback = () => isHandled = true;
        var state = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Callback", handledCallback } };
        ((INavigationAware)this.DataContext).OnNavigatedTo("Back", NavigationMode.Back, state);
        args.Handled = isHandled;
    };
}
```

And set breakpoint to last line of the handler code.

To avoid it, assign your handler in the `OnNavigatedTo` method of your `FirstRunPage`, and unregister the handler in `OnNavigatedFrom`.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;   
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    HardwareButtons.BackPressed -= HardwareButtons_BackPressed;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this (see my updated OP) and still have the issue of the app closing when back is pressed. What I am doing is binding a the Visibility property of a Sign-in Grid and New User Grid to the View Model IsNewUser. If `!IsNewUser` then cancel navigation and change the property so I show the Sign-in Grid again. If back is pressed a 2nd time (at sign-in grid) then go ahead and navigate out of the app.

Comment: Please, can you explain little bit more why you do not want the app to be closed? Back button is used to navigate back in the stack of opened pages and if it is on last page in the stack, the app closes. If you want to provide custom undo action on your page, then you do with your own handler and set `Handled` to true. But if there is nothing to be undone, it is valid to close the app. Or I am missing something important here.

Comment: I have a nice startup hub w/ multiple sections explaining on to use the app. The last section is a sign-in section. If the user is new, they press new user and I hide the sign-in stuff and show a new user Grid. Rather than have the user press "sign-in" to re-display the sign-in stuff, I wanted to let them "navigate" back to the Sign in using the back button and handling the cancelation.

Comment: I understand how the navigation stack works, but was under the impression that I could control it regardless if there are items in the navigation stack or not. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you remove your call to ViewModel and everytime sets the `Handled` property to `false`, it will not navigate out of the app using back button. But think about the user who is not able to get out of the app with back button for no valid reason (at least to her). 
You cancel back navigation with your code and show the sign-in part of the page again. Now, when the user sees sign-in, do you want to allow her go back? If no to see pages before but close the app, navigate back through the whole backstack, if no and not close the app, `Handled=false`.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it had to be set to true to prevent navigation out of the app. I do actually handle letting them nav out. When they nav back to the sign-in Grid, my view model knows and never calls the callback, preventing the `handled = false;` from getting set and the app exiting.

Comment: Ah sorry, I meant to not call ViewModel and set `Handled=true` (not false). This will prevent using back button to navigate out of the app everytime.
I think your goal is to prevent the app going back (closing) when the user presses back button when seeing grid for new user. That works with your handler. But when she presses it with sign-in grid, it will let her navigate out. That is also valid.

Comment: That's what I need to have happen, but setting it to true the first time doesn't cancel the navigation. I'm not sure why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66327/discussion-between-martin-konopka-and-johnathon-sullinger).